# Laravel Sail Paradox - There are any way to install without php and composer installed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

Laravel Sail, has a good premisse to create a zero dependency environment, with, php, redis,  mariadb etc...

But its instalation require composer, composer require php installed,

is this a paradox?

There are some way to achieve zero dependency, with docker installed?

Comment: Laravel requires PHP and composer.. if you don't want those then don't use laravel sail and conifgure your own docker env..

Comment: This isn't so much of a paradox. The idea of having Sail (or Docker in general) is provide a specific application environment for testing and eventually deployment. Most people will have PHP installed locally, and your IDE will likely depend on it too. This PHP installation may be customized, a different version, or be built with different extensions than your project requires, yet the build tools will still run.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**edit**

I was listening to the laravel news podcast yesterday and the people from Laravel created a solution for this problem. They now have [a section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects) with a command that spins up a php container to install php dependencies through a container first and move them to your host computer.

```bash
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

---

As Sail gives you the option to manage the container from the host through Artisan, then **no**.

If you don't mind to give up the ability to use Sail in this way and just want to set up a dockerized environment for Laravel, then **yes**. You can make [a container](https://github.com/thomasmoors/laravel-docker) for php in which you copy your project and through volumes maps to the host. You can enter a container (as if using `ssh`) through `docker-compose exec <service> <command>`, in the repo I linked, the php Dockerfile uses Alpine as the linux distro, which comes with the `ash` (instead of `bash`) shell. Because of his you can run

```bash
docker-compose exec php ash
```

to enter the container and run commands inside it.

Comment: Save my live sir, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects

You can use the sail Docker container on its own to bootstrap the process, and run `composer` in that container. The main part of that documentation is this command:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

There is a `laravelsail/php7.4:latest` container too, if you are not yet using PHP 8.

---

Edit: the above *used to* work, but now appears to be broken. The container does not have a `sail` user or group, and that leads to permission problems.

When the `sail up` command is executed, the entrypoint to the PHP container will take the current user ID and group ID, then assign them to the `sail` user and group. That happens (now) in the `sail up` command and not the `laravelsail` container listed above.

I'm not sure when this changed. For now you can run the above without the `-u` option, and set up the application as root within the container. Permissions will need to be manually fixed after that.

Also note the `laravelsail/php7.3` container only has `composer` v1.8 installed initially, but is easily updated using `composer self-update`.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me on windows:

```
docker run -v /c/xampp/htdocs/boilerplate:/var/www/html -w /var/www/html composer install  --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting up Laravel Sail on a machine that has local setup & then using this command `sail artisan sail:publish`

> After running this command, the Dockerfiles and other configuration files used by Laravel Sail will be placed within a docker directory in your application's root directory. After customizing your Sail installation, you may wish to change the image name for the application container in your application's docker-compose.yml file. After doing so, rebuild your application's containers using the build command.